# Is it possible to redirect ODBC connections to another IP address

Tags: mysql, deployment, odbc

We have a building full of computers, each of these computers has a number of ODBC connections setup pointing at a MySQL server at a certain IP address.

We want to move this MySQL server to another machine and we are wondering if there is a way to set something up at the original IP address to redirect any ODBC connections pointed at port 3306 to the new machine.

Some background, both the old and new servers are Windows Server 2003. The MySQL server is part of a legacy system, we are replacing this with a SQL server but the MySQL needs to remain operational for the forseeable future.

The alternative is to spend a day going around each computer and amending the ODBC connection strings, which I will do if I need to but thought I would ask on here first.

Thanks

Comment: Voting to move to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure if it would be better on here or SF, can I do anything to move it over or do I need to wait for an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, most of which are network related, not software.

In the future, consider using a hostname rather than an IP address for configuring your ODBC settings. This allows you to utilize DNS to resolve a hostname to any IP address that you want.

Besides that, [MySQL proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) may be what you are looking for.